# correct way to free up memory for an array of Objects containing an array of Objects in C++

Tags: c++, memory, free

I have something like this:

```
class HashTable
{  
  Bucket<E>** index;
  ...
}

 ~HashTable( ) 
 {
     delete[] index;
 }

 class Bucket
 {
    E* elements
    ...
 }

 ~Bucket( ) 
 {
     delete[] elements;
 }
```

How do I correctly free up the memory in this case?

Is delete[] index enough, or do I have to cycle throug all Bucket-Objects and delete elemtents-array seperatly?

Comment: I cannot see any allocation with `new` operator. If you use `delete` you have to allocate with `new` first.

Answer (score 2):

If you allocated  each bucket object seperately using `new` you should deallocate each using `delete`.
The simple rule is:
You should have as many number of `delete` or `delete[]` as many `new` or `new[]` you have respectively.

Suggestion:
You might do yourself a favor by using smart pointers and saving yourself from such memory management problems.

Comment: what's with the destructers, aren't they supposed to do this for me?

Comment: @user1308532: Destructors **Do Not** deallocate dynamic memory by themselves.Dynamic memory is explicitly asked for by calling `new`, `new[]` or `malloc` & **must** be explicitly deallocated by calling `delete`, `delete[]` or `free` resp.

Answer (score 0):

The HashTable contains a double array (I suppose), so it has to be deleted like this:

```
delete[] index[0];
delete[] index[1];
...
delete[] index;
```

If any of those levels are not arrays, but single pointers, you leave out the `[]`.

The `Bucket` class, as you've written it, is fine, it will automatically delete its array and the `E`'s in it.

Comment: if I do a delete[] index[0]; the Bucket's destructor will be called, am I right?